# Total variation distance for dependent product measure using coupling

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, coupling

If $B_1, ..., B_k$ are $k$ random variables that are dependent. And $R_1, ..., R_k$ are independent variables, such that the total variational distance satisfies $d(B_i, R_i)\leq \epsilon_i$ for all $i$. Can we say that

$$d((B_1, ..., B_k), (R_1, ..., R_k))\leq \epsilon_1 + ... + \epsilon_k$$

In particular, if $B_1, ..., B_k$ are independent, this this follows. However, my random variables are dependent.

Comment: Total variational distance, definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures)

Comment: That should not be true: just think  $(R_1, \ldots, R_n)$ could have the $same$ marginals  distributions as $B_i$, but  $not$ independent,  so the distributions of $(R_i)$ and $(B_i)$ are not the same, so there is some distance $> 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I did figure out that cannot be true.